# Le verbe français « sonner » et le verbe anglais « sound »

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

Quand est-ce que le verbe *sonner* peut traduire le verbe anglais *sound* ?

Quelques exemples :

> 1) Independent platform software would sound very "computer jargon".
>
> Un logiciel de plate-forme indépendant sonnerait très "jargon informatique". (?)

Also, picking sentences from here https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/sounds

> 2) "It sounds dull to me," Dulce said, and stood.
>
> "Cela me sonne/semble terne," dit Dulce en se levant. (?)
>
> 3)  Sounds like a good job for a woman, doesn't it?
>
> Cela semble/sonne être un bon travail pour une femme, n'est-ce pas? (?)
>
> 4) It sounds like a fairy tale.
>
> Cela ressemble/semble/sonne à un conte de fées. (?)
>
> 5)That sounds like someone thought he was important.
>
> Cela ressemble à quelqu'un a pensé qu'il était important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sonner* en français est utilisé pour donner son impression sur la qualité sonore ou phonétique d'un son, ou d'un mot voire de toute une expression, tandis que "sembler" est plus général et porte plutôt sur les apparences générales de quelque chose, quelqu'un ou d'une situation. On peut dire par exemple:

> J'aime bien le titre *Les Sous-doués en vacances*, je trouve que ça sonne bien.
>
> C'est nouveau ces petits lotissements individuels, c'est quoi ? Ah, ça existe depuis toujours ?
>   Mais comment ça s'appelle ? Le... gnouf !? Ça sonne bien ! (tiré d'un sketch de l'humoriste Pierre Palmade, où il joue un jeune homme naïf qui découvre le service militaire. *Gnouf* désigne la prison en argot et a une sonorité assez drôle.)
>
> Quand il chante, ça sonne faux.

La même expression au sens figuré

> Quand Macron parle, ça sonne faux (= je ne crois pas qu'il soit sincère)
>
> Tape sur le mur, ça sonne creux (= ça donne un son qui indique qu'il y a du vide derrière la paroi ou sous la surface, que le mur n'est pas plein)
>
> Le dernier Daft Punk sonne très disco-funk.
>
> Quand tu dis "crisse, j'ai garé mon char et je suis allé magasiner", ça sonne très québecois.
>
> Le nom "Wii" sonne très "gamin", "Playstation" sonne plus "adulte", et pour certains, "Xbox" pourrait même sonner comme un nom de sextoy.

Le sens et l'usage est donc plus restreint que l'anglais "to sound", qui ne porte pas seulement sur la qualité sonore mais sur l'aspect ou sur un jugement plus général porté sur quelque chose, sur quelqu'un, sur une situation, etc.:

> That sounds like a plan - ça m'a l'air d'un bon plan, on est d'accord, ça me semble ok
>
> That sounds really boring - ça a l'air vraiment ennuyeux, ça semble vraiment ennuyeux
>
> That sounds like someone thought he was important - on dirait bien que quelqu'un s'est cru important
>
> Sounds like a job for a woman - ça a tout l'air d'un boulot de femmes (rem: je me désolidarise de cet exemple aux relents sexistes).
>
> That sounds like a fairy tale - ça ressemble vraiment à un conte de fées

(On peut aussi imaginer *ça sonne comme un conte de fées* ou familièrement *ça sonne très "conte de fées"* mais plutôt si on juge de la forme sonore du récit, par exemple, si quelqu'un raconte une histoire en commençant par "il était une fois un pauvre garçon qui rêvait de devenir riche, etc")

Comment: Une réponse parfaite. Je te remercie !