# Emploi de "me" pour "de moi"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Dans une chanson du Roi Lion, le personnage de Scar chante à un moment :

> Je dis compromission
>
> Je dis conspiration
>
> Je crie humiliation
>
> **Trois mots qui me feront**
>
> Un roi incontesté
>
> Respecté, salué
>
> Le seul dieu vivant qu'on acclame

De prime abord, je trouve que l'emploi de "me" sonne incorrect, et même en analysant je me dis que "me" ne peut pas remplacer "de moi" mais "à moi", ce qui n'est pas possible ici.

Ce type d'emploi est-il possible ou s'agit-il selon vous d'une erreur volontaire due à un certain assouplissement des règles que certains se permettent dans la chanson ?

Comment: Off topic: *sonne incorrect*, comment dire,  « [sonne l'anglicisme](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33467/le-verbe-français-sonner-et-le-verbe-anglais-sound) »...

Answer (score 4):

Je m'accorde avec l'OP pour trouver la construction pour le moins curieuse.

La justification apportée par @jlliagre tiendrait bien la route si on avait eu :

*"Trois mots qui me feront roi"* Car, effectivement *roi* est à ce titre sans conteste possible **attribut** de l'objet *me*.

Or, dans la construction * *"Trois mots qui me feront **un** roi"*, peut-on encore dire ce *roi* attribut ?

Je ne pense pas. Je crois que dans ce dernier cas, on a bien une @¹##@@ de @@## de construction de type *N faire de N N*, autrement dit une phrase à **double complément** dans laquelle on peut très légitimement tenir le dernier syntagme nominal pour un **objet direct** standard.

Si on tourne la phrase en question, un :

*Qui me fera roi ?* s'entend sans problème mais, ne préférera-ton pas assurément :

*Qui fera **de moi** un roi* à

*Qui me fera un roi* ? construction pour le moins insolite et certainement sujette à une tout autre compréhension.(1)(2)

Je crois donc avec @Destal que l'on est fondé à analyser cette phrase comme :

Sujet *faire* COI COD

avec, ici Scar dans le rôle de... COI. ;-) => *de moi* et non *me*.

---

Dans cet exemple particulier, on concluera donc sans doute sur une *licence poétique*. (La stricte correction grammaticale s'effaçant manifestement devant la volonté de rester sur un hexasyllabe.)

---

<sup>DISCLAIMER : Je crois avoir vu parfois passer la possibilité de tenir un COD pour attribut d'un COI. C'est **très** rare et entraîne toujours des interprétations ambigües. Mais ça existe.</sup>

---

<sup>1 :id si *qui -> qu'est-ce qui* qui conviendrait mieux à l'exemple de l'OP)</sup>

<sup>2 :  on peut par exemple penser à une reine veuve dans son lit ou se croire dans un atelier de fabrication de jeux d'échec. ;-)</sup>

Comment: Oui, bien sûr. +1

Comment: Je trouve la typographie des notes trop petite pour mes yeux. Est-ce vraiment necessaire?

Comment: @Lambie : Je vous présente toutes mes excuses. D'autant plus honnêtement que, pour vous avouer : Pour moi aussi. J'ai dû faire une fausse manipe quelque part mais je ne la vois pas.

Comment: Ha! Si! J'avais deux <sup> imbriqués.

Answer (score 3):

Note: Cette réponse est focalisée sur l'expression ***faire roi*** et néglige l'article dans *trois mots qui me feront **un** roi incontesté*.

La bonne analyse se trouve [icitte](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40074/1109)

---

Ce n'est pas une erreur ou une licence poétique mais une tournure littéraire établie:

> Fais-**moi** roi

est équivalent à

> Fais **de** **moi** **un** roi (ou fais **de moi le** roi)

comme

> **Me** faire roi

est équivalent à

> Faire **de moi** le roi.

[TLFi : Faire](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire)

> C.− Donner une qualité, un caractère, un état à.
>   1. **Faire qqn** + subst. (attribut de l'obj.) non déterminé. Élever au rang de, donner le titre, la dignité de. *Faire qqn héritier, chevalier de la Légion d'honneur.* Synon. nommer, instituer, constituer. *En le faisant roi, on l'avait condamné à mourir sur le sol où s'est mêlée la poussière de saint Louis et de Henri IV* (Chateaubr., *Mém.*, t. 3, 1848, p. 650). *Le jeune marquis avait cru s'acquitter envers sa femme en la faisant marquise* (Sandeau, Sacs,1851, p. 46).
>   − P. ext. Rendre, faire devenir. *Cette aventure me fait homme* (Ricœur, *Philos. volonté*, 1949, p. 179).
>   − Faire qqn juge de. Laisser à quelqu'un le soin de juger, d'apprécier.

Comment: Ceci étant, je suis parfaitement d'accord avec les soupçons de l'OP. Le côté attributif de *roi* est sévèrement plus douteux si précédé d'un article. Les exemples du TLFi sont certes justes mais il *la fait marquise*, *le fait homme*. Je crois qu'il en irait différemment si il avait voulu faire *une marquise* ou *un homme*.

Comment: Effectivement tes exemples me paraissent tout-à-fait logiques mais je pense que @aCOSwt a mis le doigt sur ce qui me dérange. Si ç'avait été "trois mots qui me feront roi", je n'aurais pas été choqué.

Comment: Oui, je suis passé à côté de la question. J'étais trop focalisé sur l'emploi de *me* pour *de moi* mais c'est effectivement la présence d'un article qui dérange ici.

Answer (score 2):

Effectivement, le pronom personnel de la première personne du singulier est *me*, placé avant le verbe, s'il remplace un nom qui ne prendrait pas de préposition (attribut du sujet, complément d'objet direct) ou  qui prendrait la préposition *à* ou *pour*, mais jamais la préposition *de*.

En français moderne, on pourrait tourner la phrase de deux manières. La plus évidente est de dire « fera de moi un roi incontesté » ; c'est un sens courant du verbe *faire* ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) III.D) : « faire X de Y » signifie à peu près « transformer Y en X » (cela s'applique aussi bien pour des choses que pour des personnes). Ce sens convient parfaitement au contexte : Scar décrit le processus politique par lequel il compte être reconnu comme roi.

On peut aussi dire « me fera roi de manière incontestée » ; c'est une construction plus rare ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) III.C.1) qui signifie nommer quelqu'un à un poste officiel ou lui conférer un titre. Ce sens était encore utilisé au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle mais a pratiquement disparu aujourd'hui (on le trouve peut-être encore dans certains actes juridiques, je n'ai pas vérifié). Dans ce deuxième sens, *me* est analysé comme COD et *roi* comme attribut du COD. « Roi » ne prend pas d'article, et ne peut pas être qualifié d'« incontesté » puisque le titre auquel Scar veut être nommé est celui de roi, pas celui de roi incontesté. Dans ce contexte, le sens est plus imagé : le processus que décrit Scar n'est pas un processus officiel, ce qui donne une portée plus forte à la phrase. Avec ce sens, Scar exprime que **c'est ce processus qui lui donne sa légitimité**. Et cela lui permet de dire qu'il sera fait « roi incontesté » : il ne serait pas seulement roi par succession, ou par application d'un processus légal, mais par l'acclamation du peuple.

En chanson, on peut se permettre un ordre de mots inhabituel ou des tournures plus rares. Ici, il s'agit d'une construction du verbe *faire* qui a disparu vers le 18<sup>e</sup> siècle, dans laquelle le sens de conférer un titre peut prendre un article.

> la société royale de Londres le fit un de ses membres, & il en fut secrétaire après la mort d'Oldenbourg ([Louis Moréri, *Grand dictionnaire historique*, 1674](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yFKcdMA0IqIC&pg=PA373&dq=%22le+fit+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNhqaopKnlAhUDxoUKHfDiCa8Q6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22le%20fit%20un%22&f=false)
>
> Son mérite lui procura le Consulat, & lui mérita la confiance de l'Empereur Othon, qui le fit un de ses Généraux. [*Nouveau Dictionnaire Historique-Portatif*, 1779](https://books.google.fr/books?id=r7w5AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA300&dq=%22le+fit+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE_7HAq6nlAhUsyIUKHal4A5w4ChDoAQg4MAI#v=onepage&q=%22le%20fit%20un%22&f=false)

Ces exemples sont un peu différents, parce que le déterminant est « un de » et pas « un », mais je suis à peu près sûr d'avoir déjà lu des exemples avec « faire X un Y » dans de la littérature d'avant le 19<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Je dois dire que pour respecter la métrique, j'aurais plutôt écrit ici « Trois mots qui me feront / Le roi incontesté » ou « Trois mots qui me feront / Roi incontesté » avec *roi* prononcé en deux syllabes. Cela dit, l'utilisation de *un* se défend, parce qu'elle permet de placer Scar dans la continuité des rois qui l'ont précédé, et introduit un contraste avec *le* dieu mentionné en suite.

Answer (score -2):

On peut dire "se faire roi".

> Il a voulu se faire roi.

C'est-à-dire se couronner soi-même ou devenir un roi par ses propres moyens.

On utilise "se faire petit", "se faire beau", etc... avec des adjectifs,
mais la construction peut aussi se faire avec un nom.

> Dion dit qu’Auguste voulut se faire appeler Romulus; mais qu’ayant
>   appris que le peuple craignait qu’il ne voulût **se faire roi**, il
>   changea de dessein.

*Montaigne - L'esprit des Lois.*

> La négociation manqua, et Charles de Bourgogne, qui voulait ajouter à ses États la Lorraine et la Suisse, était bien sûr, s’il eût réussi, **de se faire roi** sans la permission de personne.

*Voltaire - De la Bourgogne, et des Suisses ou Helvétiens*

---

Se faire roi à soi, n'aurait pas de sens.

Il parle à quelqu'un.
Il *me* parle.
Il *lui* parle.

Ici, le pronom COI est "me" et "lui".
Parce qu'on dit parler *à quelqu'un*, et pas "parler quelqu'un, ce n'est pas un COD.

Il voit quelqu'un.
Il *me* voit.
Il *la* voit.

Ici, les pronoms COD sont "me" et "la".
(Ce n'est donc pas le même "me")

Se faire roi *à quelqu'un* n'existe pas comme expression, et n'aurait pas de sens.

C'est *moi* qui fais *moi* roi.
Qu'est-ce que je fais roi? Moi. COD.

---

Pour le "un", c'est parce qu'il y a une adjonction derrière.

Je suis la reine incontestée des petits fours.
Je me nomme la reine incontestée des petits fours (je me nomme dans le sens de me conférer un titre)

Je suis le roi incontesté des gâteaux à la vanille. = il n'y en a qu'un.

Je suis un roi incontesté des gâteaux à la vanille = Je suis un des rois (parmi d'autres rois)

De là, se faire le roi/un des rois incontesté, etc...

Mais c'est surtout parce qu'il y a une clause qui suit, que le "un" est utilisé.

Un roi incontesté, salué, respecté.

Pas n'importe quel roi, mais un roi qui appartient à l'ensemble "roi incontesté, salué."

[image: Sous-ensembles]

L'ensemble B est l'ensemble des "rois".
Le sous-ensemble A est l'ensemble des rois qui ont cette caractéristique, d'être incontestés, admirés, etc.

Comment: Merci, mais voir les autres réponses pour ce qui pose problème, l'article indéfini "un". Quant à "me", après vérification il peut autant être COD (accusatif, "moi") que COI (datif, "à moi") : "il me parle" = "il parle à moi", "il m'aime" = "il aime moi".

Comment: "me" peut être un des pronoms COI, c'est vrai. mais faire roi *à quelqu'un* n'a pas de sens, et n'existe pas comme expression. Par contre "parler *à* quelqu'un existe.

Comment: Pour le "un", j'édite ma réponse pour ajouter ces infos.

Comment: Merci de laisser un commentaire, par politesse, si ma réponse est fausse, c'est la moindre des choses.

Comment: Je n'ai pas downvote mais je pense que ta réponse est hors-sujet pour la première partie, et est sans doute fausse pour la deuxième partie (en tout cas ton explication sur "un des rois" ne me convainc pas quant à la légitimité de "cela me fait un roi incontesté").

Comment: Voilà, j'aime mieux les commentaires, pour discuter comme des êtres humains. Downvoter et se barrer ensuite, il n'y a rien de plus lâche sur internet, mais c'est la sale attitude ici qui est courante.

Comment: Donc je réponds: la première partie: Elle définit ce que veut dire "se faire roi". (=C'est-à-dire se couronner soi-même ou devenir un roi par ses propres moyens.), elle donne des exemples trouvés dans la littérature. Donc, elle ne peut pas être HS. Ensuite, ma 2ème peut être fausse, je n'ai pas la science infuse,mais c'est celle qui paraît la plus logique, elle n'a pas été expliquée dans l'autre réponse.