# *N faire de N N* / COD, pas COD / Test de passivation

Tags: grammaire

La réponse simple, et sur laquelle je ne reviens pas, que j'ai apportée à [la question de @Destal emploi de *me* pour *de moi*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40072/emploi-de-me-pour-de-moi) m'a fait prolonger à des cas qui, pourtant du même genre (*N faire de N N*), me deviennent impossibles à analyser dans la même ligne :

- *Les FSEiens ont fait de ma contribution la meilleure réponse à la question de Destal*

*la meilleure réponse à la question de Destal* ressemble bien ici à un SN COD SAUF... sauf qu'il ne tient pas le test de la passivation :

*la meilleure réponse à la question de Destal a été faite de ma réponse par les FSEiens.* ne tient évidemment pas la route.

De même :

- *Un récent événement a fait de Gilles le champion d'une cause perdue.*

*Le champion d'une cause perdue a été fait de Gilles par un récent événement.*
idem, ne tient pas.

Le SN ne tient pas le test de la passivation => ne peut être tenu pour un COD. Bref! C'est plus la même limonade.

Si, seuls les COI (*ma contribution / Gilles*) me semblent indiscutables en tant que tels, on fait quoi là ? Attribut du COI ? HaBon ?

Et accessoirement, cf la forme du commentaire de Stéph, les COI qui eux supporteraient bien le test de passivation et deviendraient de ce fait COD ???
Habon!

Comment: Il me semble que c'est un cas d'attribut du COD. Ah pardon, du COI.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Je veux bien dans la mesure où je ne vois rien d'autre. Maintenant qu'est ce qui différencie ces phrases (ci-contre)  de *"J'ai fait de ce bois une bonne flute"* dans laquelle *une bonne flute* est sans aucun conteste COD ?

Comment: Ha ? Pourrait-ce être une question *d'agentivité du sujet* ? Houla! Il me semble que c'est eau-qui-dort le spécialiste de ce genre de considération. Help please!

Answer (score 2):

Vous intervertissez le COI avec le SN COD:

> Les FSEiens ont fait de ma contribution la meilleure réponse à la question de Destal.

Les FSEiens ont fait la meilleure réponse à la question de Destal de ma contribution.

Ma contribution a été faite la meilleure réponse à la question de Destal par les FSEiens

> Un récent événement a fait de Gilles le champion d'une cause perdue.

Un récent événement a fait le champion d'une cause perdue de Gilles.

Gilles a été fait le champion d'une cause perdue par un récent événement.

Comment: le verbe c'est inverser, me semble-t-il

Comment: @Lambie *Intervertir* ne te plait pas ?

Comment: @jlliagre Pas trop. Je préfère inverser l'ordre de x.

Comment: @Lambie Le sens n'est pas strictement le même. *Interverti* sous-entend qu'il s'agit d'une erreur, *inverser* seulement que l'ordre précédent a été modifié, sans préjuger de sa justesse.

Comment: Inverser consiste à remplacer une chose par son inverse. Intervertir consiste à permuter deux éléments. Ici, je parle bien d'avoir considéré un objet à la place de l'autre. Il n'existe pas "d'inverse" à la notion de COI.

Comment: De plus on parle de la nature ou du rôle grammatical des objets, qui ne dépend pas de leur ordre ; c'est précisément le sens de ma démonstration. Il serait donc curieux de parler d'inversion de l'ordre du COI et du COD, puisqu'il s'agit bien de dire qu'on a pris l'un pour l'autre et non de les avoir rangés dans le désordre.