# Comment traduire Brainstorming et Brainchild avec plus de force ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, néologismes, mots-composés

La langue anglaise a ce don pour rendre les mots composés percutants à tel point qu'on utilise rarement leur traduction française.

Comment pourrait on traduire Brainstorming et Brainchild afin qu'ils sonnent aussi bien qu'en anglais et renvoient une image forte ?

Je précise ma question: je n'attends pas la liste des traductions proposées par les différents dictionnaires mais bien un travail créatif de votre part !

Comment: J'ai très souvent entendu ***remue-méninges*** pour *brainstorming*. Tout en étant ‘hors-jeu’ pour cette question, "tempête cérébrale" semble convenir à *brainstorm*

Comment: Savoir-faire, laissez-faire, etc. Ces expressions-là sont utilisées tels quels en anglais. [On ne dit pas qu'une expression sonne bien.]

Comment: @Lambie Ces expressions-là sont utilisées **telles quelles** en anglais.

Comment: @Lambie Et *ça sonne bien* en parlant d'une expression ne pose pas vraiment de problème, même si ça sent un peu l'anglicisme : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33467/le-verbe-fran%C3%A7ais-sonner-et-le-verbe-anglais-sound

Comment: @jlliagre Ouais, so who can spell in French? I surely cannot.

Answer (score 4):

**Brainstorm/Brainstorming**

A ma connaissance, il n'y a rien d'aussi "fort" en français que le "brainstorm" anglais. Le "remue-méninges" de l'académie, même s'il fait référence au "remue-ménage" pour l'idée de la tempête/de l'agitation et aux méninges pour le cerveau, ressemble pour moi au mieux à un mauvais calembour... Et je ne crois pas que dans quelque endroit que ce soit, à part peut-être au québec, l'emploi du mot brainstorm pose problème à qui que ce soit, c'est un terme anglais entré dans le language courant comme week-end.

**Brainchild**

Celui-ci, même si le nom est assez explicite, j'ai dû en confirmer la signification par une recherche. Je n'ai pas l'impression de l'avoir souvent vu ou entendu en français. Si je réfléchis à comment on exprimerait ce concept, je pense à des tournures comme:

> Cette création, c'est un peu le bébé de Jean Dupont

> Tout le mérite de cette création revient à Jean Dupont

> Jean Dupont est le papa de cette création

En parlant d'un concept ou d'une idée, je pense que le terme "bébé" renvoie le même sens que "brainchild", dans la mesure où la relation au cerveau est implicite, on comprend bien  qu'on ne parle pas d'un vrai bébé...

Answer (score 1):

Brainstorming:

**Qu’est-ce que le brainstorming et comment fonctionne-t-il ?
Le brainstorming est une technique de groupe populaire pour trouver des idées qui reposent sur une créativité spontanée et non filtrée. L’idée d’entraîner le cerveau à laisser jaillir une « tempête d’idées » (traduction littérale) et à mettre ces dernières sur papier si possible sans se censurer, a été formulée pour la première fois en 1939 par l’auteur américain Alex F. Osborn et développée par le théoricien en management Charles Hutchison Clark. La méthode de brainstorming vise, pour faire simple, à collecter des idées rapidement et sans filtre. *En français, on parle parfois de « salade d’idées » ou de « tour de table* ».**

[brainstorming en français](https://www.ionos.fr/startupguide/productivite/brainstorming/)
Traduction: faire le/un tour de table

Brainchild

brainchild
noun
(informal)   bébé m
The scheme is his brainchild
**Le projet est son bébé.**

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/brainchild/566926)

brainchild
[ˈbreɪntʃaɪld  ]
NOUN
**trouvaille f (personnelle)**  ⧫ **invention** f
It’s his brainchild.
**C’est lui qui l’a inventé.**

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/brainchild)

Comment: J'aime bien tour de table et salade d'idée. Par contre dans bébé il manque le cerveau. Et invention est déjà la traduction de invention.

Answer (score 1):

What about

- **Brainstorm**: une **tornade** d'idées / un **bouillon** d'idées. "*Bouillon*" could mean something boiling or some yeast culture (bouillon de culture). In both cases, you have the idea of something of a loud collective emulation
- **Brainchild**: une idée (resp. projet, œuvre, réalisation) dont quelqu'un aurait **enfanté** (lit. *gave birth to*)

Comment: Bouillon d'idées est pas mal. Par contre dans enfanté il manque le cerveau.

Answer (score 1):

> *Session/séance/rencontre/réunion... de production d'idées*. (inspiré de la définition de [*remue-méninges*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=brainstorming&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) sur Franceterme)
> *Recherche/exploration/découverte collective d'idées/solutions (spontanées)*. (inspiré de la définition de [*remue-méninges*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8400452) sur GDT)

On doit savoir de la désignation de cette technique (aux résultats parfois [discutables](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming#Inventaire_chronologique_d%27%C3%A9tudes_et_d%27enqu%C3%AAtes)) qui origine de l'univers de la [publicité](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming#Origin)  qu'il n'y a **aucune *tempête*** et qu'il s'agit plutôt d'une [*attaque*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Problem_Solving#Creative_Problem_Solving_(r%C3%A9solution_de_probl%C3%A8mes_par_la_cr%C3%A9ativit%C3%A9)) (« l’attaque d’un problème dans un style commando », Wikipédia) ou d'un *assaut* (de *to storm* : « *To assault (a stronghold or fortification) with military forces* ») ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming#%C3%89tymologie_et_traductions)), autrement on n'aura pas compris l'anglicisme que l'on emploie, alors comment pourrait-on en évaluer la teneur pour le traduire, et incidemment juger de la valeur de *remue-méninges* ? La différence entre le *remue-méninges* formel et informel qui justifierait deux termes m'apparaît entièrement arbitraire et inutile. Si on veut parler d'appliquer la méthode originale de *Osborn*, on peut aussi le dire.

Quant au *brainchild*, c'est simplement *l'idée de quelqu'un* reflétant sa *vision* des choses ; on trouvera de meilleures suggestions dans les autres réponses.

Comment: *Brainstorming*, une mode arrivée jusque dans les administrations poussiéreuses quand les chefs de services répondaient à des directives types kolkhozes, mode URSS … réunions souvent dirigées par des formateurs spécialisés (autoproclamés/incompétents) ou psy inexpérimentés en stage de formation, mais de militaires, point … le nouveau millénaire parle d'*agilité* (simiesque, sans doute :-)… Les ateliers théâtres en mode "impro" sont mille fois plus créatifs.

Comment: @Personne Je vois que vous n'êtes pas particulièrement impressionné vous non plus. Partager ses idées sans contraintes peut être utile, encore faut-il être conscient des contraintes en entreprise (hiéarchie, normativité) et adapter la méthode. L'idée de maximiser les idées dans un minimum de temps en entreprise trahit un désir de rationalisation et non évidemment de fournir un forum où la personne s'exprime. Par ailleurs la réponse n'est pas vraiment accessible pour le débutant, est trop opiniâtre. Je pense que créativité et recherche vont de pair ; on doit ne rien prendre pour acquis.

Comment: C'est la richesse du site de permettre d'exprimer différents points de vue et retours d'expériences, hors rigorisme académique et conceptualisme universitaires, lorsque cela est possible ou induit par la question. La recherche est plutôt liée à l'innovation, l'invention (on sait ce que l'on veut trouver) ou à la sérendipité, hasard des découvertes. La créativité demande qu'il y ait un don particulier, une inspiration imprévisible, une capacité à saisir et mettre jour les trésors cachés de la vie que l'on éprouve à chaque instant …

Comment: … en ce sens la recherche est conceptuelle (liée au mental, à la matière grise, aux mots/nombres), la créativité spirituelle (liée à l'esprit, à la conscience, aux perceptions sensorielles/subtiles) on ignore le futur et on accueille ce qui se présente pour le magnifier … mais je ne sais pas si cela convient à @WaterBearer. Pour *Brainstorming*, j'ai atteint mes limites

Comment: Bonne remarque sur "storm"

Comment: @WaterBearer Merci, probablement que la réponse devrait consister en la première phrase suivie de la dernière ; c'est long longtemps...

Answer (score -3):

Note : Il ne faut pas faire l'erreur d'appeler ces mots des mots-valise; ces termes ne sont aucunement de cette sorte : ce sont de simple mots composés ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_compos%C3%A9#Types_de_mots_compos%C3%A9s)).

**I**

**A**

**a/** « Brainstorm »([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/brainstorm_2)) dans le sens de « incapacité soudaine de penser clairement, de progresser dans le fil de la pensée, » ne nécessite pas la création d'un nouveau terme à mon avis ; il s'agit simplement de ce que l'on a appelé depuis assez longtemps « **blocage** » et il n'est nul besoin de formuler le mot « cerveau » pour que le terme ait toute la force qui est nécessaire.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RSRgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&dq=%22blocage%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjen9DX2srsAhWNA2MBHaL1AI4Q6AEwAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22blocage%22&f=false)) Oui, vous pouvez éviter le blocage. Se bloquer est un état mental. Avoir des doutes quant à la voie à prendre est complètement normal, mais cela ne doit pas vous paralyser ni vous bloquer.

**b/**   Dans le sens de « soudaine bonne idée » je ne vois pas ce qui peut être plus expressif que les termes habituels de base, **idée de génie/géniale**, **bonne idée**, **idée imbattable**, etc. Il n'y a qu'un problème, on ne traduit pas l'idée d'occurrence soudaine qui se trouve dans « brainstorm » et c'est un élément à ajouter dans une traduction soit par un adjectif soit au moyen d'un adverbe.

- J'ai soudain/tout à coup eu une idée à toute épreuve.
- Il lui est venu une soudaine idée miracle.

Soit dit en passant, je ne trouve pas que l'idée de tempête soit créatrice de force  d'expression, ou en d'autres terme, d'expressivité, comme  elle apparait rapidement comme étant sans pertinence. Il me semble qu'il n'est pas question de perturbation mentale, de chaos, mais au contraire de l'étape finale d'une convergence (possiblement houleuse) vers l'harmonie, cette harmonie elle-même, qui est en d'autre termes l'idée soudaine, la solution.

**B**

Le mot « brainchild » a pu acquérir en anglais une expressivité particulière indépendamment des analogies qu'il suscite ou peut-être justement pour celles-ci mais je ne pense pas que l'idée de ces analogies soit d'un grand intérêt ; elle n'est pas tellement différente de l'idée que l'on trouve dans l'anglo-saxon "house of bones" pour nommer le corps humain, une idée intéressante, certes, mais le charme et l'innocence de cette antique imagerie n'est plus de notre temps, et ne laisse même dans l'anglais moderne qu'une trace résiduelle ; je ne pense pas donc que l'expressivité réside en la forme elle-même mais plutôt en ce qu'elle évoque de contextes marquants. Il me semble que la traduction « **idée originale** » ou « **création originale** » ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&client=firefox-b-d&ei=Oe6SX86JLNyBjLsP-MiRmAE&q=brainchild%2Cfran%C3%A7ais&oq=brainchild%2Cfran%C3%A7ais&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIJCAAQyQMQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BAgAEEc6CAgAEMkDEJECOgIIADoFCC4QkQI6AgguOgcIABDJAxANOgYIABANEB46BQghEKABUOsqWPFNYI1SaAFwAngAgAHgA4gB-AuSAQcwLjkuNC0xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiOiqHc-8rsAhXcAGMBHXhkBBMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)) est suffisamment expressive et qu'il n'y aucune raison d'envier à la langue anglaise un « brainchild » dont elle a en grande partie éliminé la « race » au cours des siècles.

Comment: "Brainstorm » dans le sens de « incapacité soudaine de penser clairement, de progresser dans le fil de la pensée, » ne nécessite pas la création d'un nouveau terme à mon avis" ; **Cela est faux. "brainstorm" n'a jamais voulu dire ça. Il ne faut pas confondre brainstorm et brain fog.

Comment: @Lambie It's specific to British English: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/brainstorm_2

Comment: @Lambie — Dans l'hexagone on n'utilise que *brainstorm**ing*** avec le sens que vous lui donnez https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/brainstorming utilisé à l'origine par le  monde psycho-sociologique et adopté ensuite dans les recherches/projets innovants.

Comment: @LPH apparemment vous avez vos raisons linguistico-linguistiques pour ne pas aller dans le sens de la question, ce qui vaut des votes négatifs à votre réponse. C'est pas grave !

Comment: @WaterBearer I don't think I am diverging too much; I do reckon with the necessity of identifying those concepts and I fail to situate the terms in question more thouroughly in not taking into account the gerund "brainstorming", if that is an error. I think that the negative votes are due rather to the demistification aspect I indulge in and to the orientation I give to the vocabulary from a morphological point of view. (Je m'aperçois que je vous ai lu en français tout d'un coup; j'espère que c'est sans  problème ; laissez moi savoir sinon.)